# Can't get Custom Column of type Publishing Image to display in JSLink

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, custom-list, site-column, jslink

I have a column of type "Publishing Image" named "Picture Upload" defined at the site collection level, and then included in my Custom List. When I try and access the column from my JSLink function, it won't work. If I console.log the CurrentItem, the column won't show up at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is SharePoint being difficult? Has anyone else run into a similar problem?

EDIT: I am using CSR/JSLink on the DispItem.aspx form, with the default web part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the field included in `ctx.currentItem` it must be added to the view. So you have to make sure that the field is actually in the view you are applying the JSLink on.

If this is in a list form you must make sure the "ShowInEditForm" / "ShowInNewForm" / "ShowInDisplayForm" properties (depending on which form) is set to a True on the field (you can do this with PowerShell or when defining /creating the field with code / XML).

If you do not want it in the view, for some reason, you must use client object model to retrieve the value of that field for every single item

Comment: The JSLink is on the Display form rather than a list view. I have confirmed the Column is visible in all of my Views as well.

Comment: Is the field visible there then? If not, enable the "ShowInEditForm" / "ShowInNewForm" / "ShowInDisplayForm" properties on the field

Comment: Field is visible in default form (using ServerRender) but not when using CSR/JSLink, as I cannot find it in the CurrentItem object.

Comment: Strange, the I am out of ideas. You sure it is not in CurrentItem but named with its internal name?

Comment: Checked, I've got 19 fields, all of them accounted for. Adding or remove the column appears to have no effect on CurrentItem.