# JSLink: Publishing image field shows in page edit mode but not when page is saved

Tags: publishing, jslink, image

Similar to this:
[Can't get Custom Column of type Publishing Image to display in JSLink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110852/cant-get-custom-column-of-type-publishing-image-to-display-in-jslink)

Publishing image field (Picture1) is in the list view

Image shows up correctly in edit mode but not when page is saved

All the other fields referenced in the jslink file display correctly.

```
function CustomItem(ctx) {    

var ret = "<div class='bxslide'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Picture1 + "<br /><div class='link-item'><a href='" +  ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</a></div><p>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Summary + "<br /><a href='" + ctx.CurrentItem.Link_x0020_calc  +  " '>Read more &raquo;</a></p></div>";
return ret;
```

What makes this behavior even more bizarre is the same set up works fine in another site, and the rendered html is the same on a published page as it is on the unpublished one on this site. It looks like either something is getting stripped out or one of the multitude of Msft js files isn't firing.

I also just noticed if I detach the page from the page layout, the publishing images do render. They disappear as soon as I reattach to the layout.